# Rename Subdirectories Recursively

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, rename, fd

I am trying to rename the following directory structure

```
Tests Directory
├── Test1 Directory
│   ├── 2 - 1. Data
│   ├── 3 - 2. Data
│   ├── 4 - 3. Data
│   ├── 5 - 4. Data
│   ├── 6 - 5. Data
├── Test2 Directory
│   ├── 2 - 1. Data
│   ├── 3 - 2. Data
│   ├── 4 - 3. Data
│   ├── 5 - 4. Data
├── Test3 Directory
│   ├── 2 - 1. Data
│   ├── 3 - 2. Data
│   ├── 4 - 3. Data
│   ├── 5 - 4. Data
│   ├── 6 - 5. Data
```

With

```
Tests Directory
├── Test1 Directory
│   ├── 1. Data
│   ├── 2. Data
│   ├── 3. Data
│   ├── 4. Data
│   ├── 5. Data
├── Test2 Directory
│   ├── 1. Data
│   ├── 2. Data
│   ├── 3. Data
│   ├── 4. Data
├── Test3 Directory
│   ├── 1. Data
│   ├── 2. Data
│   ├── 3. Data
│   ├── 4. Data
│   ├── 5. Data
```

If I run `fd -t d -x rename 's/^(\d+ -)\s(\d+.)/$1/'` in `Test1`, `Test2` & `Test3` - it works.

However, I want to use the command in `Test` so that I do not have to run the command in each directory.

I have tried

```
% find . -type d -exec rename 's/^(\d+ -)\s(\d+.)/$1/' {} \;
% find . -type d -exec rename 's/^(\d+ -)\s(\d+.)/$1/' {} ";"
```

Nothing is working. What can I do?

Adding more details.

```
% find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -execdir echo {} \;
./.
./Test1 Directory
./2 - 1. Data
./3 - 2. Data
./4 - 3. Data
./5 - 4. Data
./6 - 5. Data
./Test2 Directory
./2 - 1. Data
./3 - 2. Data
./4 - 3. Data
./5 - 4. Data
./Test3 Directory
./2 - 1. Data
./3 - 2. Data
./4 - 3. Data
./5 - 4. Data
./6 - 5. Data
```

**PS**, The directory names have spaces.

Comment: `find . -type d -execdir rename 's!^\./(\d+ -)\s(\d+\.)!$2!' {} +`

Comment: @αғsнιη it works. Please add it as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of problems with your `find` attempts, but you're on the right path.

1. Limit the depth of `find` recursion so the renamed directories are not themselves searched. use the `-maxdepth` option for that, and note that it must come *before* the tests but *after* the root (i.e. between `.` and `-type d`).
2. Because your `rename` command assumes you're in the directory directly above the one you're renaming, you need to use the `execdir` action instead of `exec`. Like most of the other actions, `exec` is done from the `find` top directory (i.e. `.` in your case), and it is passed the entire path from the top to the "found" entry, not just the bare filename (i.e. in your case, `exec` is passed something like `./Test1/2. - 1. Data`). `execdir` fixes both of these issues.

Comment: Should I use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir rename 's/^(\d+ -)\s(\d+.)/$1/' {} \;`

Comment: the directory names have spaces.

Comment: I think you need -maxdepth 2 (it counts from 1). If it doesn't work please substitute rename with an action that prints the current directory _and_ the entry being acted on, for debugging.

Comment: If your regexp is right (and I have not tested it), spaces should not matter. That's the advantage of using `find -exec` or `find -execdir` over the bad old `xargs` way.

Comment: It is still not working. Added `find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -execdir echo {} \;` output in the question.

Comment: Ok sorry I guess I overlooked that even with `execdir` you still get the leading dot-slash in the names.

Comment: The solution that is working for me is `find . -type d -execdir rename 's!^\./(\d+ -)\s(\d+\.)!$2!' {} +`